# Collapse sections in cshtml view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

Is there a way to collapse a razor code block or `section` in a cshtml file?

[image]

As you can in the image above, the `div` is collapsable but not the `section` or the code block.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this Visual Studio extension:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc07ec7e-abfa-425f-bb65-2411a260b926

One of the reviews claims that it allows you to collapse @helper and @section code blocks in MVC4 views but it doesn't seem to work for everyone.

Comment: Doesn't work for cshtml files (VS 2013). Asked the dev to add support. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a section in CSHTML files like this:

```
<!-- #region name -->
    wrapped content...
<!-- #endregion -->
```

This works at least since VS2015:

[image]

Note: You can even wrap the HTML comments in CSHTML comments (`@* ... *@`)